# Numpy array get the subset/slice of an array which is not NaN

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, slice

I have an array of size: (50, 50). Within this array there is a slice of size (20,10).
Only this slice contains data, the remainder is all set to nan.

How do I cut this slice out of my large array?

Answer (score 5):

You can get this using fancy indexing to collect the items that are `not NaN`:

```
a = a[ np.logical_not( np.isnan(a) ) ].reshape(20,10)
```

or, alternatively, as suggested by Joe Kington:

```
a = a[ ~np.isnan(a) ]
```

Comment: Although with this, you have to know in advance the shape of the non-NaN area. OP, do you know this in advance?

Comment: Good question to the OP, by the question text it seems that the final shape is known. But this approach could be used if at least the number of cols or rows is known...

Comment: On a side note, it's cleaner (though a touch less readable) to just use the `~` operator instead of `logical_not`. E.g. `a[~np.isnan(a)]`.

Comment: thank you very much for this tip! I actually did not know about this... I will edit the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Do you know where the NaNs are? If so, something like this should work:

```
newarray = np.copy(oldarray[xstart:xend,ystart:yend])
```

where `xstart` and `xend` are the beginning and end of the slice you want in the x dimension and similarly for y. You can then delete the old array to free up memory if you don't need it anymore.

If you don't know where the NaNs are, this should do the trick:

```
# in this example, the starting array is A, numpy is imported as np
boolA = np.isnan(A) #get a boolean array of where the nans are
nonnanidxs = zip(*np.where(boolA == False)) #all the indices which are non NaN
#slice out the nans
corner1 = nonnanidxs[0]
corner2 = nonnanidxs[-1]
xdist = corner2[0] - corner1[0] + 1
ydist = corner2[1] - corner1[1] + 1
B = copy(A[corner1[0]:corner1[0]+xdist,corner1[1]:corner1[1]+ydist])
#B is now the array you want
```

Note that this would be pretty slow for large arrays because `np.where` looks through the whole thing. There's an open issue in the number bug tracker for a method that finds the first index equal to some value and then stops. There might be a more elegant way to do this, this is just the first thing that came to my head.

EDIT: ignore, sgpc's answer is much better.

Comment: the NaNs will change so I will not know where they will start, only that the finite area will be contiguous. I want to slice out the finite are and still keep a 2D shape but numpy will not do this: zz = obj.lat2d[np.isfinite(obj.lat2d)] zz.shape is (33024,)

Comment: Edited my answer, see above, or see sgpc's answer.